# tc prio qdisc example not working

Tags: tc

I'm used tc to priority send packets to port 9999.

```
tc qdisc add dev eno1 root handle 1: prio priomap 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
tc filter add dev eno1 protocol ip  parent 1: prio 0 u32 match ip dport 9999 0xffff flowid 1:1
```

use ethtool to limit eno1 bandwith to 10Mbps,and test with iperf.

```
iperf -c 192.168.1.23 -p 9999 -b 50M -i 1 -t300
iperf -c 192.168.1.23 -p 29999 -b 50M -i 1 -t300
```

the result is packets sent to 9999 and 29999 are almost the same,port 9999 has no higher priority。both the iperf clients send 5Mbps.I hope to send 10Mbps to port 9999.

so how can I set up?